# Библиотека/Компонент редактирования текста

Tags: javascript, reactjs, поиск-библиотек, wysiwyg

Подскажите готовые библиотеки, компоненты, для текстовых полей.  Чтобы пользователь мог вставить текст, и отредактировать его (добавить курсив, жирность, табуляцию, выделить участок кода, и тд).

Очень желательно чтобы это была компонента для реакта, но не обязательно

Comment: https://jpuri.github.io/react-draft-wysiwyg/#/

Comment: Это называется `wysiwyg` вроде

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите на сайт [bit.dev](https://bit.dev/primefaces/primereact/editor). Это поисковик готовых компонентов с предпросмотром прямо в браузере

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]